# How can I convert wordpress backend editor time from 24 hour to 12 hour format

Tags: wordpress

I need to convert the time on backend published time in wordpress from 24 hour to 12 hour format.

[image]

I tried using this code

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'my_post_submitbox_misc_actions' );
function my_post_submitbox_misc_actions($post){
 echo 'test';
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

In admin area, go to Settings -> General, there you have the settings to change how time and date should be displayed. See image for result

[image: Settings]

[image: Result]